# Why is getMethod deprecated and how do I fix it in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php

Why is getMethod word slashed in my code and error says:
Function 'getMethod' has been deprecated. The $upper functionality will be removed and this will revert to its PSR-7 equivalent
PHP(PHP6406)
function Request::getMethod(bool $upper = false): string
Get the request method.

@param $upper: Whether to return in upper or lower case.

I used CodeIgniter and tried looking for solutions but can't seem to fix it.. does anyone know how to solve this?

```
 public function insert()
{ 
    if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $validation = \Config\Services::validation();

        $rules = [
            "txtSN" => [
                "label" => "Student Number",
                "rules" => "required"
            ],
            "txtFN" => [
                "label" => "First Name",
                "rules" => "required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]"
            ],
            "txtMN" => [
                "label" => "Middle Name",
                "rules" => "required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]"
            ],
            "txtLN" => [
                "label" => "Last Name",
                "rules" => "required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]"
            ],
            "cbSex" => [
                "label" => "Sex",
                "rules" => "required"
            ],
            "txtDOB" => [
                "label" => "Date of Birth",
                "rules" => "required"
            ],

        ];
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb4WX.png)

Comment: The method is not deprecated, just the parameter. Unfortunately there isn’t currently a universal way to annotate the deprecation of the parameter so [CI has decided](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/7334) to annotate the method. Another [here](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/4717) says you’re just going to have to ignore it for now.

Comment: Does it not affect my code?

Comment: I’ve never used CI before, however from what I’ve read, as long as you don’t pass anything to that method you should be okay.